# Ajax and Django

Tags: ajax, django

I have a jquery ajax code that looks like below,Its working on a delete button and a checkbox.

```
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
                    $("table 
 tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked")){
                                        var value = $('chk').val();
                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: "/delete/",
                                          //  type: "post", // or "get"
                                            data: value
                    });
                });
            });
            });
```

This jquery call should delete the checked row in a table and the added ajax call will call a django view.

My doubt is I am passing the checkbox value to django view in the above AJAX call. In this case how do django view come to know what table row to delete based on the checkbox value?

below is how my table is getting created in a for loop

```
{% for x in dirs %}
                       <tr id='this_row' style="text-align: center;">
                                  <td>

                                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="this_row" name="record"></td>


                          <td>
                              <a href="/contents?query_name={{ x|urlenchode }}" id="this_row1" style="text-decoration: none;">{{ x.name }}</a>
                          </td>
                                    <td>
                              {{ x.created_date }}
                          </td>
                                    <td>
                              {{ x.description }}
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                     {% endfor %}
```

below is the delete button

```
<button type="submit" name="erase" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
```

Comment: It is in the `data (`value`).

Comment: If you're using a loop to generate row in table, please add it

Comment: I am writing my django view like below,def RecordDeleteView(request):
    value = request.GET.get('value', None)          . After that I am not sure how to use this value variable to identify the records to delete

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `id` of the row as `value` attribute to the checkbox, so your ajax will send a list of ID. Instead of `this_row`, add `{{x.id}}` the instance id

```
{% for x in dirs %}
    <tr id='tr-{{x.id}}' style="text-align: center;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk-{{x.id}}" value="{{x.id}}" name="record"></td>
       <td>
       <a href="/contents?query_name={{ x|urlenchode }}" id="link-{{x.id}}" style="text-decoration: none;">{{ x.name }}</a></td>
       <td>{{ x.created_date }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.description }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And in your ajax, you have access to it with

```
// send this array via ajax
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
   var id_list = new Array();

   $("input[name=record]:checked").each(function(){
       id_lists.push($(this).val()); 
       $(this).parent("tr").remove(); // Remove the row,
       // the correct is parent() without 's', not parents()
   });

   // with type:'post', don't forget the csrf_token
   $.ajax({
       url: "/delete/",
       type: "post",
       data: {
          id_list:id_list,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{ csrf_token }}"
       },
   });
});
```

And in your view, you can retrieve the `id_list` containing all the selected rows with `reqest.POST.getlist('id_list[]')`. In case it was a GET request `reqest.GET.getlist('id_list[]')`

Comment: My table looks like this .I am putting the id of 2nd <td> ELEMENT in the value of the first <TD> which is a check box.  This is what you suggest if I am correct                                                                            
                       <tr style="text-align: center;">
  <td>

 <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="this_row" name="record"></td>
<td> <a href="/contents?query_name={{ x|urlencode }}" id="this_row" style="text-decoration: none;">{{ x.name }}</a>
              </td></tr> </table>

Comment: edit your question, with the whole table. do you render these rows with a for loop?

Comment: i have added the for loop code where the table is created. Please check. Yes the table is created in a for loop.

Comment: Check my answer! I updated it. replace `this_row` by `{{x.id}}`